# Use sp_MSforeachtable for creating table backups dynamicaly

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to use sp_MSforeachtable to create backup tables dynamically using this query.

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable
@command1='Print ''[?_bckp]''', 
@command2='select * into ''[?_bckp_2022]'''' from ?;'
@whereand=' and o.Name in (
''<table list>''
) 
and schema_name(schema_id) = ''dbo'''
```

I'm getting an error for @whereand but I think it is a bogus error. I think the problem is in the command2 at [?_bckp_2022]. The table name is coming out of command1 is looking like [[dbo]].[table_name]]_bckp]. I think the sql command generated in command2 is causing the error at the execution stage.
My questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I remove schema out of the table-generated name in command2?

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, don't rely on undocumented procedures like this. Rely on your own procedures where you have full control on how they operate (and probably are more reliable).

Comment: You're missing a comma before @`whereand`; saying that you have unbalanced quotes and why are you quoting the target table name? Just use `sys.tables` to build a dynamic query.

Comment: I was missing a comma. Thanks. LOL. If you look at the code for too long you see what you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a comma missing. Thank everyone.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, it is much easier to do it using `sys.tables`.

Use `string_agg` to concatenate the dynamic command and `exec()` to execute it

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select  @sql    = string_agg ('select * into ' + quotename(name + '_bckp_2002') + ' from ' + quotename(name), ';' + char(13))
from    sys.tables t

print   @sql
exec    (@sql)
```

You can filter the required tables easily in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: I'm on SQL server 2016. Thanks

Comment: use `FOR XML PATH` instead of `STRING_AGG()`